# Create-Fixture in Pester (Powershell BDD) isn't working

Tags: powershell, bdd, pester

I'm following the instructions from here:

http://scottmuc.com/blog/development/pester-bdd-for-the-system-administrator/

I'm finding that having installed and imported the module I still can't run Create-Fixture.

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Create-Fixture isn't a cmdlet any more. I had a look here:

https://github.com/mwrock/Chocolatey-Packages/blob/master/pester/Pester.psm1

and realised the name of the cmdlet has been changed. It's now called New-Fixture.

If you run New-Fixture it even references Create-Fixture:

```
PS D:\edsource\Powershell> New-Fixture
invalid usage, please specify (path, name)
eg: .\Create-Fixture -Path Foo -Name Bar
creates .\Foo\Bar.ps1 and .\Foo.Bar.Tests.ps1
```

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. I think it got renamed to conform to the PowerShell cmdlet naming convention. Thanks for the heads up.